# Slow UIWebView rendering in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebview to display graphs in real time. The graphs-page refreshes every 5 seconds. There is a JS that displays the graphs by getting data. As the data changes quite quickly, the graphs are supposed to refresh as well, to display the updated data. While the graphs reload, a loading image appears. In Android, iOS, Safari and Chrome the rendering is very fast, no loading image appears but in the UIWebview it takes very long to render & show the loading image. I have tried using WKWebView, same there.

Code

```
NSString* urlGmap=[NSString stringWithFormat:@“http://www.example.com”];
NSURL *url_gmap = [NSURL URLWithString:urlGmap];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url_gmap  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData  timeoutInterval:60];
[ webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I am using just a UIWebView by providing the url of the webpage.

Comment: Why are you ignoring locally store cached data? Loading some resources from cache would significantly speed load time up.

Comment: I have tried that but does not help me

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 8, you can use `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`.
**`WKWebView` uses Nitro javascript engine.**